# Copy database data from one server to another server

Tags: sql

I need to copy all my data from a database on Server "x" to server "z". Both have the same data base name and table names. I need to copy my prod data to my test server without loosing my test servers data.

Comment: Check out SSIS that will allow you to migrate data. The best method is to just take a backup from Server X and restore on Server Z

Answer (score 2):

Try using SSIS to copy your databases. You can also use replication (push or pull or even merge), or you can manually backup a db as a *.bak file then create and restore it onto another server.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA242aMvz6E

Comment: I cant use backup I cant loose the procs and table structure

Comment: You do not lose that if you do a full backup and restore.